# Is there a slang word/phrase for "Floor it"?

Tags: slang, word-requests

英辞郎 gives アクセルをべた踏みする as one of the translations of "floor it" but while this has the same meaning, it can't really be used in the imperative. I mean,「べた踏みしろー！」「べた踏みにしようぜ！」sounds rather...uncool, doesn't it?

How would this kind of thing be said in 走り屋 or maybe 暴走族 lingo?

※It doesn't have to be the exact meaning of pressing the gas pedal to the floor, I am more interested in what phrases are actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **アクセル全開**で行こうぜ！

or

> **フルスロットル**で行こうぜ!

or

> **アクセルペダル目一杯**踏もうぜ！

**Let's go at full throttle!/Full Blast!**

should work.

I guess *アクセルをべた踏みする* is probably used when you need to accelerate very hard like slope. So, you might be told like that by the teacher at driving school.

Comment: Are you saying that these are phrases that would actually be used by people in the 走り屋 or 暴走族 cultures?

Comment: Yes. I think the culture is shrinking, young people do not buy and drive cars as before. Therefore probably manga or video game 30 years ago  describes the expressions actually used in the sort of situation. autonomous driving and strict regulations will get widespread. I do not suppose the culture will sustain.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a slang sentence at all. Natural use.

Comment: If you have phrases to correspond to, you can answer with it.